# Add a new column using regex pandas

Tags: python, regex, pandas

Hello I have a df such as :

```
COL1 COL2
A g1
B g1.t1
C transcript_id "g1.t1"; gene_id "g1"
D g2
E g2.t1
F transcript_id "g2.t1"; gene_id "g2"
G transcript_id "g2.t1"; gene_id "g2"
```

and I would like to add a new COL3 where I only put `gvalue` for each row

Here I should get :

```
COL1 COL2                               COL3
A g1                                    g1
B g1.t1                                 g1
C transcript_id "g1.t1"; gene_id "g1"   g1
D g2                                    g2
E g2.t1                                 g2
F transcript_id "g2.t1"; gene_id "g2"   g2
G transcript_id "g2.t1"; gene_id "g2"   g2
```

I tought I could use something like re.sub ?

I tried :

```
table[COL3]= re.sub(r'(?<=transcript_id )*.+(?<=gene_id ")','',table[COL2])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it:

```
df['COL3'] = df.COL2.str.extract('(g\d+)')
```

Output:

```
  COL1                                 COL2 COL3
0    A                                   g1   g1
1    B                                g1.t1   g1
2    C  transcript_id "g1.t1"; gene_id "g1"   g1
3    D                                   g2   g2
4    E                                g2.t1   g2
5    F  transcript_id "g2.t1"; gene_id "g2"   g2
6    G  transcript_id "g2.t1"; gene_id "g2"   g2
```